# AngularJs: Convert json string to html table

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I am an absolute newbie to angularjs and i have been making my hands dirty from the past 3 days. Now, the requirement is to convert a json string from the rest end point to tabular data. Here is the code i am trying.

```
 $scope.getDataCatalogue = function(){

       $http.get('http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=485a35b6b9544134b70af52867292071&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json')
           .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                 //do something with your response
                 $scope = data;
           })
           .error(function(error){
                 console.log("not world");
           });
  }

   $scope.getDataCatalogue = function(){
    alert('getDataCatalogue');
   }
```

Now,how can i convert the json to grid from the data. Is this the right way to approach the problem.

Comment: There are very less chances that you will find boilerplate could to do this, If you try to form a table by yourself after sorting the data it would be the best

Comment: is your data coming in a fixed known structure ? I mean is the number columns/properties in your object the same always ?

Comment: Ok check my answer below, if its descriptive enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed structure coming out of the data then you can simply make use of `ng-repeat` to iterate through the object(data) and display it on your pre-created table. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pj5br/)

Example shown below:

Considering this is your object which your assigning to a `$scope` variable name people. `$scope.people = data;`

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      firstName: "Peter",
      lastName: "Jhons"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      firstName: "David",
      lastName: "Bowie"
    }
]
```

In your controller:

```
.success(function(data, status) {
    $scope.people = data;
 });
```

In your HTML :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either do it yourself in the view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header 1</th>
            <th>header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
            <td>{{row.attribute1}}</td>
            <td>{{row.attribute2}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Or use a library like ui-grid to render a more advanced table.